# libSVM classification not working

Tags: libsvm

First of all I apologize for the generic title but I can't really understand what's my problem.

I've just built libSVM 3.17 and I'm trying to use it, I've noticed that it can't predict a thing on my testset.
So I did some tests with a very very small problem. Here is what i do:

3 classes, 2-dimensional feature vectors, basically 3 clusters of points. This is the training file:

```
1 0:1 1:1 
1 0:1.1 1:0.9
1 0:1 1:1.2
2 0:10 1:11
2 0:9 1:10
2 0:10 1:12
3 0:50 1:52
3 0:49 1:50
3 0:48 1:49
```

Training the model with

```
libsvm-train.exe -t 0 data.txt model
```

(so, using a linear kernel which should be more than  enough here)
yields the following model file:

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type linear
nr_class 3
total_sv 4
rho -1.26244 -1.04645 -1.58585
label 1 2 3
nr_sv 1 2 1
SV
0.01414027149321267 0.000445053674077491 0:1 1:1.2 
-0.01414027149321267 0 0:9 1:10 
-0 0.0007109847138286527 0:10 1:12 
-0.000445053674077491 -0.0007109847138286527 0:48 1:49
```

Now, predict: this is the test file:

```
1 1
10 11
49 49
```

And the output is

```
1
1
1
```

with an accuracy of 33%.

I'm completely new to libSVM and I'm clearly doing something wrong here, reading [LibSVM FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html) doesn't really help me.

Thanks for any input provided.

Comment: If that is actually your test file, the format is wrong. 
Try using your training file as a test file. You need to select a suitable value for `-c cost` parameter by trying different values with validation data. Read http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

Comment: Yep thanks, I had just figured out that the test format was completely wrong. The one thing I don't get is, why do I have to provide labels in the first column of the test file? I don't have them for all my testset, my ground truth is quite limited..

Comment: The labels in the test data get used for the accuracy calculation. If you don't know the labels just put any value in the label field, but then of course the accuracy is meaningless. Unlabelled test data still has a label field just to make things a bit simpler, so that libsvm doesn't have to know how to read two different formats and so that you don't have to tell it which the format is.

Comment: Yep, I figured that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data format is not properly inserted. 
LIBSVM data format is consisted of the pair :. The value of  is an integer starting from 1. So I think you should try to change the number of . for example, 0 to 1 and 1 to 2.. something like that.

Here is my suggestion!

```
1 1:1 2:1 
1 1:1.1 2:0.9
1 1:1 2:1.2
2 1:10 2:11
2 1:9 2:10
2 1:10 2:12
3 1:50 2:52
3 1:49 2:50
3 1:48 2:49
```

Also you can check [README](https://github.com/arnaudsj/libsvm/blob/master/README) for libsvm in the section of "Installation and Data Format".
I hope it can help your problem.

Cheers!!